# Rake is aborting because undefined method `inet' for sqlite db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, postgresql, devise

My Rails application uses two databases, first is postgresql and second -sqlite, the last for test environment. I used Devise gem which uses inet data type to carring infomation about IP. It works well for postgresql, but couses some errors for sqlite. I had installed a gem postgres_ext and added it to Gemfile, but it didn't solve the problem. Below is a piece of log:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=test rake db:setup
(in /user/project)
db/test.sqlite3 already exists
-- enable_extension("plpgsql")
-> 0.0030s
-- create_table("comments", {:force=>:cascade})
-> 0.3368s
-- add_index("comments", ["commentable_id"],         
{:name=>"index_comments_on_commentable_id", :using=>:btree})
-> 0.1680s
-- add_index("comments", ["commentable_type"],        {:name=>"index_comments_on_commentable_type", :using=>:btree})
-> 0.1898s
-- add_index("comments", ["user_id"], {:name=>"index_comments_on_user_id", :using=>:btree})
-> 0.1568s
-- create_table("contacts", {:force=>:cascade})
-> 0.2803s
-- create_table("delayed_jobs", {:force=>:cascade})
-> 0.2818s
-- add_index("delayed_jobs", ["priority", "run_at"], {:name=>"delayed_jobs_priority", :using=>:btree})
-> 0.1677s
-- create_table("exercises", {:force=>:cascade})
-> 0.3360s
-- create_table("languages", {:force=>:cascade})
-> 0.3025s
-- create_table("levels", {:force=>:cascade})
-> 0.2692s
-- create_table("solutions", {:force=>:cascade})
-> 0.3262s
-- create_table("users", {:force=>:cascade})
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `inet' for   #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x00000007563ec8>
/home/mtczerwinski/Projekty/ruby/railsilla/db/schema.rb:104:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

and so on.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: can you post your schema.rb, and also migration file creating table users (it's located under db/migrate/, will be something like *timestamp*_create_users.rb)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

PostgreSQL has a native [`inet` type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-net-types.html#DATATYPE-INET):

> **8.9.1. inet**
>
> The `inet` type holds an IPv4 or IPv6 host address, and optionally its subnet, all in one field. [...]

but SQLite doesn't. Apparently your `users` table has an `inet` column in it so that part of your schema is PostgreSQL-specific.

Using a different database for testing than you use for development and production is just as bad an idea as using different databases for development and production. ActiveRecord offers very little in the way of portability so switch your test environment to PostgreSQL too.

Comment: Is there a quick way to solve this? Which field type should we use in MySql?

Comment: Apparently we should replace it with "string" type for MySql

Comment: Isn't portability the whole point of having this DB configuration system and ORM?

Comment: @AndrewKoster In theory that's part of the point, in reality the only way to get database portability is to do it yourself the hard way.

Answer (score 23):

You can replace it with "string" type and it will work

```
# pg
# t.inet     :current_sign_in_ip
# t.inet     :last_sign_in_ip

# mysql
t.string     :current_sign_in_ip
t.string     :last_sign_in_ip
```

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful

Answer (score 2):

My CI/CD fires some tests to see that the build is correct, and I can't use the production database for those tests. It doesn't make sense to lose functionality and convert everything to string just because I want to test that the application has been deployed properly.
So when I deploy I copy a modified database.yml that redefines test to:

```
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

This allows me to test locally and in Travis using a proper database (the same than in production)
To avoid problems with sqlite, I redefine .inet inside the migration (only if the database is SQLIte3).

```
  # Redefine inet to string for SQLite3
  if t.class.to_s.include? "::SQLite3"
    t.define_singleton_method(:inet) do |*args|
      t.string *args
    end
  end
```

Comment: And I realized that when using the schema sometimes it fails beacuse of that, so I execute this script (before I was copying the database.yml and executing bin/rake tests)

    #!/bin/bash

    cp -f config/database.yml config/database_good.yml
    cp -f config/database_openshift.yml config/database.yml
    cp -f db/schema.rb db/schema.good.rb
    RAILS_ENV=test bin/rails db:drop db:create db:migrate
    bundle exec rake test
    result=$?
    mv -f db/schema.good.rb db/schema.rb
    mv -f config/database_good.yml config/database.yml
    exit $result